# Change Text in a button using ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to change the text in the button using angular I am pretty much done but I have a few questions.

First, my code below just changes the text when I click the first time, how can I change it again after the second click? That button is hiding a `<DIV>` so that is the reason for the change?

Angular:

```
 angular.module('test',[])
    .controller('MyCtrl',function ($scope) {
      $scope.myText = 'Press to start';
      $scope.start = function () {
      $scope.myText = 'Starting...';
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <button ng-click="start()"> {{ myText }} </button>
</body>
```

The second part of my question is:

How can I apply that code in that code up in that HTML and Angular?

HTML:

```
<a ng-click="Menu()" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-client">hide the search</a>
```

Angular:

```
$scope.Menu = function(){
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

**Changing text:**

JS

```
angular.module('test',[])
    .controller('MyCtrl',function ($scope) {
      $scope.myText = 'Press to start';
      $scope.start = function (myText) {
          $scope.myText = (myText === 'Starting...') ? 'Finish' : 'Starting...';
      }
});
```

HTML

```
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <button ng-click="start(myText)"> {{ myText }} </button>
</body>
```

**Changing class:**

JS

```
$scope.isToggled = false;
```

HTML

```
<a ng-click="isToggled = true" class="btn btn-default" ng-class="{toggled: isToggled}" id="menu-client">hide the search</a>
```

Comment: its exactly what i looking for, I just got a problem i have a jquery working on that code so now its not working anymore  look I want to say : http://jsfiddle.net/84kc7ppt/   I need change that text when is clicked and back the same when i clicked again, because I am hidden a div and unhidden, understand?

Comment: No sorry I can't understand and the Jsfiddle is not working.

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<a ng-click="Menu()" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-client">hide the search</a>
```

Angular

```
$scope.Menu = function(){
        $scope.isHedden = true;
   };
```

Now whichever element in the HTML that you want to hide/show, use ngHide directive for that:

```
<some-element ng-hide="isHidden">Some plain text or value goes here</some-element>
```

Look out https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide for more details on this directive.